# Cannot connect to Wi-Fi Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, netplan, systemd-networkd

I cannot connect to my Wi-Fi network on my freshly installed `Ubuntu 20.04 server` (no other packages except `wireless-tools` were installed).

First, I checked (with `lspci`) that my Wi-Fi adapter (`Network controller Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)`)
is detected by the system.
Then, I checked the interface name with

```bsh
foo@bar: iwconfig
docker0   no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Then, I added the interface name `wl2ps0` into an `netplan` configuration file
`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "MyNetworkSSID":
        password: "MySecretPasswort"
```

and rebooted the system. After rebooting, the system did not connect to the Wi-Fi and the interface `wlp2s0`

```bsh
foo@bar: ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e4:4f:68:02:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b0:10:41:84:69:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:61:94:e2:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

is `DOWN`.
I tried to activate it with
`ip link set wlp2s0 up` but this had no effect (the interface is still `DOWN`).

What is the issue here?

Comment: Is the indentation correct? there should be two more spaces before `password:` as it's a key for the `"MyNetworkSSID" network.

Comment: It worked without the indentation for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you cannot connect because the package *wpasupplicant* also needs to be installed. With a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, please do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wpasupplicant
```

Then try again:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```