# Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS is unable to detect Wi-Fi adapter

Tags: 20.04, wireless

My computer (Advantech ITA-5231) had been running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS without any problem. Recently I tried to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS but it was unable to detect Wi-Fi adapter. During the installation and using ls /sys/class/net after installation did not dhow any wlp device. It can still detect LTE adapter and they are both mPCIe modules. I have tried to do the following but the issue was not fixed.

1. Install libnl-route-3-200_3.4.0-1_amd64.deb, libpcsclite1_1.8.26-3_amd64.deb,wpasupplicant_2.9-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
2. Reboot the computer
3. Re install Ubuntu Server 20.04

After that I tried to run live Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 (from USB) and there was no problem detecting Wi-Fi adapter. Turning back to Ubuntu Server 20.04, the Wi-Fi adapter was not found again.

What could be the problem here? Why Ubuntu Desktop could detect the Wi-Fi adapter but Ubuntu Server could not? Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263111/cannot-connect-to-wi-fi-ubuntu-20-04-server/1263142#1263142 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @waltinator Please see:  https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20082/what-is-a-duplicate

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you cannot connect because the package wpasupplicant also needs to be installed. With a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, please do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wpasupplicant
```

Next, find out the name of your netplan file:

```
ls /etc/netplan
```

Amend it to agree with the template here that is found in `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml`.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp2s0b1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.21/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
```

Please note that the network name, known as SSID, and the password are enclosed in quotes ". Of course, substitute your exact details here.

After making any changes, follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

You should connect immediately but it might take a reboot.